# How can I make GET and POST methods of WebAPI-MVC unambiguous

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC controller, linked to a 'Create' view.

I'd like to have a 'GET' method, in order to do some pre-processing and display the view, and then a 'POST' method, in order to update the database accordingly.

After reading a few guides, and answers on SO, I think that something like what follows is the correct solution.

```
    <HttpGet>
    Public Function Create() As ActionResult
        'Do Stuff
        Return View(New MyClass)
    End Function

    <HttpPost>
    Public Function Create(MyObject As MyClass) As ActionResult
        'Process results
    End Function
```

However, when I try to access 
http://my.site/MyController/Create, I get an exception:

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: The current request for action 'Create' on controller type 'MyControllerController' is ambiguous
```

As if the engine could not decide between the two, even if they are marked Get and Post.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. I'd be inclined to agree with Erik's answer, or there's some other reason the attribute is not actually being applied. Also, FWIW, it's unnecessary to specify `HttpGet`. That's the default.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - it's not exactly the default.  It's more like a catch-all.  If you don't specify a verb, it will be used for all verbs.  Thus you could specify EITHER get or post, but you must have differentiation on one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely you're using the wrong attribute.  MVC and WebApi use the same attribute name for HttpGet and HttpPut, but they are in different namespaces.

For MVC:

```
System.Web.Mvc.HttpGetAttribute
```

For WebApi:

```
System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute
```

If you use the wrong one (using the MVC attribute with WebApi or vice versa, then it's ignored, and you will get the error message you mentioned.  Make sure you have the right namespace.

Comment: Changing `<HttpGet>` to `<Mvc.HttpGet>` made the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload Controller methods. What you can probably do if you want really want to keep the action names same is below:

```
<ActionName("Save")>
<HttpPost>
Public Function Create(MyObject As MyClass) As ActionResult
    'Process results
End Function
```

Comment: "You can't overload Controller methods." That's not true. You very much *can* overload actions. They simply must utilize different HTTP methods, as otherwise, the routing framework can't distinguish between when to route to one or the other.